# Read from multiple excel files and Insert them into a table in PosgreSQL DB

Tags: python, excel, pandas, postgresql

I'm going to read multiple excel files located in a specific folder in PC and which are in the same construct and then insert them into the DB table in PostgreSQL. I'm reading excel files, however, I'm having an error during`cur.execute` section.

Example Excel file:

[image]

And My script:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import psycopg2
import numpy
from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter, AsIs

def addapt_numpy_float64(numpy_float64):
    return AsIs(numpy_float64)
def addapt_numpy_int64(numpy_int64):
    return AsIs(numpy_int64)
register_adapter(numpy.float64, addapt_numpy_float64)
register_adapter(numpy.int64, addapt_numpy_int64)

def connect_db(frame):
    # database connection

    print("DB opened successfully")
    sqlpart(conn, frame)


def sqlpart(conn,frame):
    cur = conn.cursor()

    sql="""INSERT INTO actuals (timeslot,unit_id,actual) 
            VALUES(%s,%s,%s) 
            ON CONFLICT (timeslot,unit_id,actual)
            DO UPDATE SET  timeslot=%s, unit_id=%s,actual=%s"""

    conn.commit()
    values=[]
    da=[]
    for x in range(len(frame)):
        da=frame[0][x],  frame[1][x],  frame[2][x]
        values.append(da)
        print(values)
    cur.execute(sql, values)
    print("everything is done")

def patika():

    path = r'mypath'
    all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")

    li = []

    for filename in all_files:
        df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=None,header=None)
        li.append(df)

    frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    #print(frame)--->> [(Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'), 200, -1000),....] values that comes from excel like this

    connect_db(frame)


patika()
```

Output:

```
cur.execute(sql, values)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: `da=str(frame[0][x]),  str(frame[1][x]),  str(frame[2][x])`

Comment: In `values`, when you print it, how many elements are in each tuple?  Are there only three?

Comment: Are you actually reading Excel (.xlsx or .xls) then I'm sorry but there is nothing I can suggest. But if are you reading .csv files then I suggest you looking into the Postgres [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) command

Comment: @bigbounty it didn't work, still same error

Comment: @MikeOrganek yes, its standard form, 3 elements in a tuple, tuples goes on if how many there much.

Comment: @belayer They are ".xlsx"  not .csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has six parameters that need to bind.  As you verified in a comment, your binding tuples contain only three elements:

```
sql="""INSERT INTO actuals (timeslot,unit_id,actual) 
            VALUES(%s,%s,%s) 
            ON CONFLICT (timeslot,unit_id,actual)
            DO UPDATE SET  timeslot=%s, unit_id=%s,actual=%s"""
```

Please update your `insert` to:

```
sql="""INSERT INTO actuals (timeslot,unit_id,actual) 
            VALUES(%s,%s,%s) 
            ON CONFLICT (timeslot,unit_id,actual)
            DO NOTHING"""
```

In case your table is unique on `(timeslot, unit_id)`, then your `insert` would be:

```
sql="""INSERT INTO actuals (timeslot,unit_id,actual) 
            VALUES(%s,%s,%s) 
            ON CONFLICT (timeslot,unit_id)
            DO UPDATE SET actual = EXCLUDED.actual"""
```

**UPDATE**
On reading more closely, you have multiple problems in your code:

```
def sqlpart(conn,frame):
    cur = conn.cursor()

    sql="""INSERT INTO actuals (timeslot,unit_id,actual) 
            VALUES(%s,%s,%s) 
            ON CONFLICT (timeslot,unit_id,actual)
            DO UPDATE SET  timeslot=%s, unit_id=%s,actual=%s"""

    conn.commit()
    values=[]
    da=[]
    for x in range(len(frame)):
        da=frame[0][x],  frame[1][x],  frame[2][x]
        values.append(da)
        print(values)
    cur.execute(sql, values)
    print("everything is done")
```

First, your `conn.commit()` is not being done after the execution of the `insert`.

Second, you are attempting to pass a `list` of `tuple` objects to your `insert` execution.

Please try something like this:

```
def sqlpart(conn,frame):
    cur = conn.cursor()

    sql="""INSERT INTO actuals (timeslot,unit_id,actual) 
            VALUES(%s,%s,%s) 
            ON CONFLICT (timeslot,unit_id,actual)
            DO NOTHING"""

    #values=[]
    #da=[]
    for x in range(len(frame)):
        da=frame[0][x],  frame[1][x],  frame[2][x]
        #values.append(da)
        #print(values)
        cur.execute(sql, da)
    conn.commit()
    print("everything is done")
```

Comment: I replaced them and nothing has changed, I still get same error.

Comment: @automatickebab  Please update your question to show what you get when you print a tuple.

Comment: value's type is `list`, when I print(values) I get--->>[(Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'), 200, -1000), (Timestamp('2020-03-01 01:00:00'),....]

values[0]'s type is "tuple", when I print(values[0]) I get--->>(Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'), 200, -1000)

Comment: @automatickebab  Please see the update to my answer I added just now.